# CSS Float : 2 Divs, 1 div = Nav, 1 div = product. Full height NAV how to do this?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to setup the following using float.
Everything worked out fine except the nav div is not full height.

Screenshot : http://postimg.org/image/gywuh9lv1/

HTML :

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='left'>NAV PANEL FULL HEIGHT, ADJUST TO AMOUNTS OF PRODUCTS</div>
 <div class='right'>
  <div class='product'>PRODUCTS</div>
  <div class='product'>PRODUCTS</div>
  <div class='product'>PRODUCTS</div>
  <div class='product'>PRODUCTS</div>
  <div class='product'>PRODUCTS</div>
  <div class='product'>PRODUCTS</div>
  <div class='product'>PRODUCTS</div>
  <div class='product'>PRODUCTS</div>
  <div class='product'>PRODUCTS</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
float: left;
```

Just for info : 
min-height:100%; NOT working.

For example : height:500px; is working but this is not dynamic, if my page has more content then it already fails.

Comment: Instead of `min-height: 100%` why not just `height: 100%` ?

Comment: Alos not working, thanks for thinking along.

Comment: faux columns: http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns

Comment: Like this - http://jsfiddle.net/mcuc9khe/

Comment: Or this - http://jsfiddle.net/co7b48cf/

Comment: I found solution myself, why faux columns ? display:table; works great and hey it's 2014 not 2010 !! So I don't care about IE7

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

**CSS**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.right {
  padding-left: 220px; /* Your left-nav width + padding here */
}
.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; /* Or a px value if there's supposed to be a margin between this and the container. */
  bottom: 0; /* Same as above */
  width: 200px; /* Or however big you want to make it. */
}
```

This solution will actually force your left nav to grow with the container, instead of just making it look that way.  It's also backwards compatible to most browsers and doesn't have any of the caveats that come with `display: table;`.

Answer (score 1):

`height:100%` will only work if your `html` & `body` are `height:100%` too ;

[Here is Codepen an example](http://codepen.io/GuillaumeGautier/pen/RNrXOQ)