# When Containers Float Everything Below Messes Up

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out why my two div containers mainContainer and sideContainer wont float next to each other and when you uncomment float, in the .container class they are perfectly next to one another but everything beneath it messes up i tried to fix this by making a parent container that would take up the entire width of the page so it would hold the entire line. Please help.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 180px;
}

#pageContent {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Navigation */

nav {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 40px;
}


/* End of Navigation */


/* Welcome Section */

#welcomeSection {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}


/* End of Welcome Section */


/* Script Section */

#scriptSection {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  //float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 300px;
}

#mainContainer {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: red;
}

#sideContainer {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: green;
}


/* End of Script Section */


/* Notes Section */

#notesSection {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}


/* End of Notes Section */


/* Footer */

footer {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 180px;
}


/* End of Footer */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body>
  <header>
    <p>Header</p>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <p>Nav</p>
  </nav>
  <section id="pageContent">
    <div id="welcomeSection">
      <p>Welcome</p>
    </div>
    <div id="scriptSection">
      <div id="mainContainer" class="container">
        <p>Main Container</p>
      </div>
      <div id="sideContainer" class="container">
        <p>Side Container</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="notesSection">
      <p>Notes</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <p>Footer</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any problem: https://jsfiddle.net/76kgfuLL/1/

Comment: Its already working what are you looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Float : 2 Divs, 1 div = Nav, 1 div = product. Full height NAV how to do this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405466/css-float-2-divs-1-div-nav-1-div-product-full-height-nav-how-to-do-this)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `clear:both` to the `#notesSection`

```
#notesSection {
    clear: both;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Or add a `div` between `#scriptSection` and `#notesSection`, then give it a style of `clear:both`

```
<div id="scriptSection">
    <div id="mainContainer" class="container">
        <p>Main Container</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sideContainer" class="container">
        <p>Side Container</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="notesSection">
    <p>Notes</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have forgotten to add `<head>` tag into your `html` code.
Then you already had the solution:

Add `float: left;` to your container.

Then you just have to add `clear:both;` to your classes `notesSection` and `footer`.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 180px;
}

#pageContent {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 100%;
}


/* Navigation */ 

nav {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 40px;
}

/* End of Navigation */ 

/* Welcome Section */ 

#welcomeSection {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* End of Welcome Section */ 

/* Script Section */

#scriptSection {height: 100%;}

.container {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 300px;
}

#mainContainer {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: red;
}

#sideContainer {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: green;
}

/* End of Script Section */ 

/* Notes Section */ 

#notesSection {
    clear:both;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* End of Notes Section */ 

/* Footer */ 

footer {
    clear:both;
    background-color: orange;
    height: 180px;
}

/* End of Footer */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header><p>Header</p></header>

  <nav><p>Nav</p></nav>

  <section id="pageContent">

    <div id="welcomeSection">
      <p>Welcome</p>
    </div>

    <div id="scriptSection">
        <div id="mainContainer" class="container">
            <p>Main Container</p>
        </div>
        <div id="sideContainer" class="container">
            <p>Side Container</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="notesSection">
        <p>Notes</p>
    </div>

  </section>
  <footer>
    <p>Footer</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```